# How to handle apostrophes & \r\n in mail function?

Tags: php, html-email

I have mail function which gets mail message from a textarea. But whenever there is apostrophes and new line it show it like below.

***Example Output:***
*Comments: You\\'re mailing address was wrong. Couldn\\'t you provide an other?
Survey Answers:
item : You\\'re making it well. Isn\\'t it?\nitem2 : It\\'d better to have a cup of tea?\n*

1) There are three slashes along with apostrophes. Is it likely something to do with magic escaping? The stripslashes function is better option for it?

2) New line converted to \r\n. The issue is the \r\n might be a windows artifact. On a Linux server it might be \n only. Is it would be enough to use str_replace('\r\n', "\n", $message); ? Then str_replace("\n", "
", $message); ?

Answer (score 1):

1) Try adding stripslashes($message); should fix the problem ;).

2) Why do you even add the \n if you remove it after with str_replace() ? Better solution for this would be using HTML in messages. Add header that supports html in message, and do break.

EDIT: I'm not sure if answer to second question is exactly what you ment. If not, please describe a little bit more, so I can help you :)!

Comment: If i add single stripslashes($message);, it still leaves one slash like ie item : You\'re in. don\'t know. item2 : Welcome to land\'s n. Is there any way to remove all the slashes at once?

Comment: You should disable magic quotes - http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Answer (score 0):

$string = str_replace(array("\n","\r\n","\"), '', $string);